# Use data type according to command line argument in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to save the data type given as a command line argument in my C program and use that type in the whole program without checking it. For example, I could run the program "./name -d int" or "./name -d float" and I want the data type to be saved for further use and to be seen in the entire program, not only in the main() function. A short example:

```
int main() {
  /* read command line argument */
  /* I would like to be able to save the type in T to use like this */
  T a[20]; 
  /* rest of the program */
}
```

Could I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't. Types are checked at compile-time. You can't declare them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by an earlier answer, you can't do this in c unless you have something like switch statements in your code that handle different cases, because data types are determined at compile time. If you are willing to settle for less than 64 bit precision for integers and you have 64 bit doubles, you can use doubles for all of your numbers and then just have switch statements e.g. when you output, that convert the double to an integer or char etc. as necessary and then output in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that in C. 
Types have to be determined are compile-time, you can't choose the type at runtime.

More dynamic languages (like Objective-C for instance) will allow you to do such things.

Why are you trying to do that in the first place ? Maybe we can provide any more guidance.

Comment: I want to implement a program which works with arrays of different types and the type is given as a command line argument as in my example.